# How to add Bootstrap JS and Jquery JS to Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's an application running on **create-react-app** [image]and **Next JS**
[image]. Difference between them is CRA seems to have loaded bootstrap.mon.js and jquery.min.js while NextJS has not. I added a HEAD section to NextJS code through next/head and attempted to load both JS files. Although there were no errors, I did not see right results either. 
Can someone help me understand why this happens with NextJS and what should I do to get NextJS load my application right with bootstrap and jquery

Comment: Code for CRA - https://github.com/KrishnanSriram/cra
Code for NextJS - https://github.com/KrishnanSriram/nextjs

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this snippet to your _app.js just above your return code

```
useEffect(() => {
import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
  }, []);
```

so your complete _app.js will be like this

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: not working for me, as it says Module not found: Can't resolve 'js/whatevermyjsis.js'

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the modules at the client-side. so you can use this

```
// _app.js

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  require("jquery");
  require("popper.js");
  require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require client-side libraries in **componentDidMount()** after installed via npm.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        require('jquery');
        require('popper');
        require('bootstrap');
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **defer** attribute in bootstrap Script tag , that will help first load jquery then load bootstrap

```
      <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js" strategy="afterInteractive" ></Script>
  <Script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossOrigin="anonymous" strategy="lazyOnload" defer/>
```